# Whitelist Azure SQL Server IP to access Az Storage Account

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-storage, azure-synapse

My Az SQL Server accesses csv files present in Storage Account by creating external table. The storage account is firewall protected with access to only some IPs. How do I whitelist my SQL Server IP to ensure access to the Storage Account? Please help

Answer (score 1):

Go to Storage account --> Networking

Select `Enabled from selected virtual networks and IP addresses` as Public network access.

[image]

Then go to Firewall section. Here you can add sql server IP.

[image]

Refer - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-network-security?tabs=azure-portal#managing-ip-network-rules

Comment: What is the SQL Server IP? Where can I find it?

Comment: Also, my SQL Server and Storage Account reside in two different tenants. This is why I am unable to use the resource instances section.